# Bitmasking and searching consecutive 1's

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, bitset

I have written code to count the continuous ones in an array or you can use binary string for convenience. Any solution using the binary string is acceptable.

My Solution is:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define MAX 100000
int main()
{
  int n,q,k,count;
  string str;
  cin>>n>>q>>k;
  bitset<MAX>s,c;
  //inserting bits in array
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    int temp;
    cin>>temp;
    s[i]=temp;
   }
   cin>>str;
  for(int i=0;i<q;i++)
  {
     //making duplicate bitset
     c=s;
     if(str[i]=='?')
      {
         count=0;
         while(c!=0) 
         { 
            //using bitmask to count maximum no of continuous 1's-O(1's bit)
            c=(c&(c<<1)); 
            count++; 
          }
      if(count>k)
         cout<<k<<"\n";
      else
         cout<<count<<"\n";
   }
   else
   {
       //shifting each bit to right and updating first bit with previous last
      // bit
       bool lb=s[n-1];
       s=s>>1;
       s[n-1]=lb;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to give an example with possible value and invalid inputs and expected outputs. it will help people to figure out the way and the purpose of your programme.

Answer (score 10):

`<bits/stdc++.h>` (like everything in your compiler's `bits/` subtree) is not a standard header and therefore not portable.  Even if you're willing to sacrifice portability, it's a poor choice, as it will slow compilation down compared to simply including what you use.

`using namespace std;` is poor practice.  It makes your code less clear, and it may even silently change its meaning.

Don't use the preprocessor to name constants.  Use a properly scoped, strongly typed C++ constant:

```
constexpr std::size_t max = 100000;
```

When using input streams, always check that operations succeed before using their results.

Variable names should be more descriptive.  I have no idea what `n`, `q`, and `k` are supposed to be storing.  In fact, these names are so useless that I gave up reading at this point - it's not at all clear what this is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 6):

- When you post code to be reviewed:

  - If your code asks for input, provide a set of valid and invalid inputs.
  - If your code output a result, show the expected output.
- Since you present your code, it may be interesting to embrace a [coding standard](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards#using-namespace-std). You do not pay taxes on written characters. Do not be afraid to use spaces to improve readability.
- [Don't include `<bits/stdc++.h>`](//stackoverflow.com/q/31816095)`:

  - It's not a [standard header](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards#std-headers). If you try to compile your code with MSVC, it will complain that the header can't be found.
  - Even if you use only GCC, it would include so much unnecessary things that your compilation time will increase considerably.
  - Instead, explicitly include all headers needed.
- [Don't use `using namespace std;`](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards#using-namespace-std) :

  - Although it's "safe" to use it in some places (e.g. implementation files), as long as you are not familiar with the features of C++, [try to avoid it](//stackoverflow.com/q/1452721).
  - It can lead to a world of name collisions. (best case)
  - It's a source of silent errors and weird bugs. (worst case)
  - If typing `std::` is so tedious for you, try to import only specific identifiers (e.g. `using std::string;`).
  - If importing individual names is still too awful for you, try to do it [inside a restricted scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-declarations) (e.g. a function) and not in global scope.
- [Don't use preprocessor macros](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/style-and-techniques#why-not-macros) to [defines constant values](//stackoverflow.com/q/14041453), instead [use const variables].(https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/newbie#const-vs-define).
- [Chose good names for variables](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/style-and-techniques#hungarian). What do `n`, `q` and `k` mean? They are `int`, but? And for `s` or `c`, we know they are `bitset<MAX>`, but nothing more.
- [Write expressive code](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rp-direct), in which your intentions are [clearly stated](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rp-what).
- [Don't declare more than one variable at a time.](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/DCL04-C.+Do+not+declare+more+than+one+variable+per+declaration) It leads to errors, especially when working with pointers or initialization.
- [Always initialize a variable](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es20-always-initialize-an-object) when you declare it.
- Extract the code into [reusable functions](https://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Ezachary/computing/lessons/uces-10/uces-10/node11.html) that are [as short as possible](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-single), and that operate a [reduced and well defined number of statements](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#f2-a-function-should-perform-a-single-logical-operation). (See [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)). (E.g. a function that asks the user to enter an input, reads them and returns them)
- If you ask user to input some values, really ask (tell to user what he has to write).
- When you read values from user input, [consider it ill-formed](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#slio2-when-reading-always-consider-ill-formed-input), so [check for validity](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#istream-and-ignore). Here you don't check after getting the `int`s. Furthermore, you don't check the length of the string  but access it by indexes, etc.
- The `main` function should return an integer.

Answer (score 5):

Don't declare multiple variables on a single line. it is error prone and more difficult to read.

```
int n,q,k,count;
```

should be:

```
int n;
int q;
int k;
int count;
```

Not sure what I mean by error prone?

```
int* n,q,k,count;
```

How many pointers do you have? one. only `n` would be a pointer in this declaration.

---

Let your operators breathe. The lack of whitespace makes your code harder to read.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    int temp;
    cin >> temp;
    s[i] = temp;
  }
```

this is a little easier to distinguish.

---

[Prefer prefix to postfix](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/60002/297895)

---

Use more consistent indentation. I had to read the code three times just to realize that the scope braces didn't line up with each other. I almost flagged to close because

```
for ()
{
}
else
{}
```

would be broken, and that's how your braces line up horizontally.

Comment: FWIW, if `*` for pointer types are written before the variable name, then the declaration becomes `int *n, q, k, count`, which is less ambiguous.

Comment: @Quelklef yes but that is also often taught as a poor practice in C++. Regardless single line multi-variable declarations are harder to read.